# How can Powershell script be invoked in a windows system from a unix system

Tags: powershell

How can Powershell script be invoked in a windows system from a unix system. I have a windows system, where the Powershell script has to run. This Powershell script must run only when it is invoked/called from another system which is a unix system. Is it possible to call a powershell script like that from a unix system. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [winexe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/).

```
winexe -U 'user%pass' //hostname 'powershell.exe my_power_script'
```

This assumes that your powershell script is located on the remote windows system.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell over ssh is one way - http://www.powershellinside.com/powershell/ssh/download.aspx